# MySQL SELECT * from one table with check records in second table

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have two tables. One of them is a table of orders. 
Each order can contain one or more jobs. 

Each job can have three states: "new", "in_progress" and "finished". 

The jobs are stored in the second table. 

Question: how to build a query to obtain a list of **orders**, where all the jobs have the status "finished" ?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**: I need to get only those orders where all jobs are finished.

Comment: [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) + [WHERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join with a little trick:

```
select o.*,(count(*) = sum(j.jobStatus = 'finished')) all_done from orders o, jobs j where 
  o.orderID = j.orders_orderID group by o.orderID having all_done = 1
```

Comment: Ok, but one order have one or more jobs. I need only orders with all jobs finished.